# How to create column in footer of Excel using HSSFFooter in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, footer, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook

I will create an Excel file using footer. In this case, the contents of the footer are three columns for signature. Is it possible to create a column in footer using .apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFooter?

The footer I will create is like this picture [image]

But when I try to using the HSSFFooter, I only contain one line. Like this pict
[image]

the first line is replace by the second line that I declare,

Here's my code :

```
HSSFFooter rowSignature0 = sheet0.getFooter();
rowSignature0.setCenter("KOLOM PROSES PENJURNALAN");

// tanggal
String now = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
counter+=1;
rowSignature0.setLeft(now);
rowSignature0.setCenter(now);
rowSignature0.setRight(now);
```

So, do you have any idea to create this footer?

Comment: Each Excel header and/or footer has three columns (left, center and right). Have you tried [HeaderFooter.setLeft](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HeaderFooter.html#setLeft-java.lang.String-), `.setCenter` and `.setRight`? If you tried, please show the used code and please tell us what problems you got.

Comment: hello @AxelRichter , I think the Excel footer just have one line, so I can't make a signature column in footer

Comment: Seems you are not clear with the terms column and line in your question. And you seems not to know what Excel sheet footers are. Excel sheet footers consist of **one** line having **three** columns. Texts in columns may have line breaks but not really single table rows. How would you create your needed sheet footer using Excel GUI? Looks as if your screen shot shows Excel sheet cells but not a sheet footer.

Comment: hi @AxelRichter the first picture is column in the body, but I want move it into the footer, but I dont know how. If it possible when I try to create multiple lines in footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel sheet footers consist of one line having three columns - left, center and right. Texts in columns may have line breaks but not really single table rows. That is how Excel provides sheet footers and even using Excel GUI one cannot really put table rows into a sheet footer.

So what one can create using Excel and comes closest to your requirement is the following:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream ;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HeaderFooter;

public class CreateExcelFooterText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  StringBuilder strFooterLeftText = new StringBuilder();
  strFooterLeftText.append("\n");
  strFooterLeftText.append(HeaderFooter.date());
  strFooterLeftText.append("\n");
  strFooterLeftText.append("Dibuat oleh");
  
  StringBuilder strFooterCenterText = new StringBuilder();
  strFooterCenterText.append(HeaderFooter.startBold());
  strFooterCenterText.append("KOLOM PROSES PENIJURNALAN");
  strFooterCenterText.append(HeaderFooter.endBold());
  strFooterCenterText.append("\n");
  strFooterCenterText.append(HeaderFooter.date());
  strFooterCenterText.append("\n");
  strFooterCenterText.append("Diperiksa oleh");
  
  StringBuilder strFooterRightText = new StringBuilder();
  strFooterRightText.append("\n");
  strFooterRightText.append(HeaderFooter.date());
  strFooterRightText.append("\n");
  strFooterRightText.append("Diahkan oleh");

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelFooterText.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelFooterText.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("A1");

  //we need more margin for the footer than the default
  sheet.setMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin, 1.5); //bottom page margin 1.5 inch
  sheet.setMargin(Sheet.FooterMargin, .75); //footer marginb 0.75 inch
  //from version 5.2.3
  // sheet.setMargin(PageMargin.BOTTOM, 1.5); //bottom page margin 1.5 inch
  // sheet.setMargin(PageMargin.FOOTER, .75); //footer marginb 0.75 inch
  Footer footer = sheet.getFooter();
  footer.setLeft(strFooterLeftText.toString());  
  footer.setCenter(strFooterCenterText.toString());
  footer.setRight(strFooterRightText.toString());

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [JXLS](https://jxls.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html)?

JXLS is a small wrapper around [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) that allows you to define a template using Microsoft Excel instead of doing everything in java code. You have small fragments of markup (for loops, value placeholders etc) in your template but the majority of the presentation logic (eg colours, bold, headers, footers, images etc) can be done in excel.

Comment: hello, maybe I will considered to using JXLS but i dont know ho to using it. The JXLS is very new thing for me.

Comment: It's much easier to create a nicely styled spreadsheet by pointing and clicking in excel than it is in java code. For simple/ugly data only spreadsheets I'll use POI directly. But when I want to create a nicely styled spreadsheet I'll use JXLS. POI code will often be a few hundred lines of data and style logic mixed together. With JXLS the java code is only for the data, all the style logic is in the template and very simple to comprehend since it's [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)

Comment: hi, dont you give me a tutorial how to create image/footer header using JXLS

Comment: With JXLS you would do all the styling (images, bold etc) in Excel and put markup (for loops, placeholders) using excel too. In java you'd merge your data with the template to create the final spreadsheet with a few lines of java code